# Removing rows where multiple columns equal an exact number R

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to subset rows where x1 and x2 == 9. My real set has over 200 columns where the column name starts with the same string. The dummy code below creates a smaller sample of the data. I'd like to do this ideally with the R data.table package if possible.

```
df <- data.frame('id'=c(1,2,3), 'x1'=c(9,9,4), 'x2'=c(9,9,4))
head(df)

# does not work, but thought perhaps I could have defined the columns via a paste and then subset where columns were equal to 9.
df[which(paste0("x", 1:2)==9), ]
```

Update: sorry if I wasn't clear. I am aware of simply adding a filter for `x1` and `x2`. The issue is that the real data consists of over 200 columns: `x1:x200`. I am in search of a cleaner solution than what is proposed below.

Comment: Since you want to use `data.table`, I'll assume efficiency matters. I'd recommend using a larger example that would work for benchmarking. Maybe something like `set.seed(47);
nc = 40;
nr = 5000;
dt = data.table(matrix(sample(c(0, 9), size = nc * nr, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1, 99)), nrow = nr));
dt$id = 1:nr;
setkey(dt, id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an efficient base R solution I would simply use `rowSums`, e.g.

```
cols <- paste0("x", 1:2) 
df[rowSums(df[cols] == 9) == length(cols), ]
#   id x1 x2
# 1  1  9  9
# 2  2  9  9
```

If you want a data.table solution, I would use a binary join, e.g.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[as.list(rep(9, length(cols))), on = cols]
#    id x1 x2
# 1:  1  9  9
# 2:  2  9  9
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:3, x1 = c(9, 9, 4), x2 = c(9, 9, 4))
```

Comment: Thank you for the DT solution and warning about apply @David Arenburg

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
df[apply(df[, paste0("x", 1:200)] == 9, 1, all), ]
```

Comment: This is actually cleaner than what I found. I consider this to be the best answer. Thank you, Gregor.

Comment: I agree this is pretty clear. If you care about efficiency, I'd recommend holding off on accepting this answer for a few hours - some data table pros will probably have better ideas that we can benchmark and find the fastest.

Comment: Okay. Sounds reasonable. Thank you again though for the answer. Saved my a few hairs.

Comment: consider accepting the answer if it solves your issue @yokota (green tick mark on the left)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper yokota  accepted my answer minutes after I posted it. I recommended they hold off a few hours in case someone has a better solution.

Comment: Alright then, but I'd be surprised, maybe `rowSums` would be faster than `apply`, or you could use `startsWith` so it's agnostic about the row suffixes, appart from this it's quite straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

A melt can allow you to not have to write out every column (for your >2 column case):

```
> aTbl = as.data.table(df)

> aTbl[, all9sP := F]
> aTbl[, .SD
       ][, !'all9sP'
       ][, melt(.SD, id.vars=c('id'))
       ][, NVars := uniqueN(variable)
       ][value == 9
       ][, .(N9s=.N), .(id, NVars)
       ][, all9sP := N9s == NVars
       ][, aTbl[.SD, all9sP := i.all9sP, on=.(id)]
       ][all9sP == T
       ][, all9sP := NULL
       ][, .SD
       ]

   id x1 x2
1:  1  9  9
2:  2  9  9
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df[df$x1 == 9 & df$x2 == 9,]
```

EDIT (misunderstood, now it should do the trick):

```
for (i in 2:200) {df = df[df[,i] == 9,]}
```

Comment: The issue though is that I have 200 columns with the similar naming convention... so x1:x200, which would make this solution kind of messy.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `grep` with `apply`

```
# Select all columns that have (colnames) "x"  
col.names <- grep("x",colnames(df), value = TRUE)
# Select rows where row == 9
sel <- apply(df[,col.names], 1, function(row) 9 %in% row)
df[sel,]
```

And the output

```
  id x1 x2
1  1  9  9
2  2  9  9
```

Comment: Thank you, @Miha. This solution works well, too. I will take Gregor's advice and try to benchmark the various solutions by the end of day for "answer".

Comment: The difference between this answer and my answer are how the column names are constructed - this is good for pattern matching, mine is good for constructing them. The meaty part of the answer is `apply` - my answer applies the `all` function, this one uses `%in%` - so mine will return TRUE only if *all* the columns are 9, this one returns TRUE if *any* of the columns are 9. You need to clarify which one you want.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution using data.table

**Create dataset**

```
ncols <- 5
cnms <- paste0("x", 1:ncols)
X <- data.table(ID = 1:1e6)
X[, (cnms) := NA_integer_]
X[, (cnms) := lapply(X = 1:ncols, sample, size = .N, x = 1:10)]
```

**Find rows where sum equals 9**

```
X1 <- X[, s := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = cnms][s == 9, ][, s:= NULL][]
X1
```

**Find rows where all columns are equal to 9**

```
X[, s := NULL]
ind <- rowSums(X[, lapply(.SD, is.element, set = 9), .SDcols = cnms])
X2 <- X[ind == length(cnms)][]
X2
```

**Edit**
This is acutally a lot faster:

```
X[, s := NULL]
ind <- rowSums(X[, .SD , .SDcols = cnms] == 9)
X2 <- X[ind == length(cnms)][]
X2
```

**Edit2**
See answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg. A lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

In the tidyverse, try `rowwise` and use `filter` as usual

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(x1 %in% 9 & x2 %in% 9 )

Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id    x1    x2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     9     9
2     2     9     9
```